# Converting dates with PHP for DATETIME

Tags: php, datetime

I know there are literally thousands of similar questions, but do not ask if it was not necessary.

I researched a lot and found all the solutions that make the conversion of dates with standard PHP functions, it works perfectly if the date to be converted to have a standard, not in my case.

I am getting data from a third party site that returns me a date in the following format:

```
12/20/2012 14:34 -> d/m/Y H:m
```

Note that besides the strange pattern has not seconds.

Problem is that I tried to use these solutions as standards strtotime and also some functions, but nothing solved my problem. I ended up creating the following solution:

```
<?php

$data = '20/12/2012 14:34';

$teste = explode('/', $data);
$teste2 = explode(' ',  $teste['2']);

$final = $teste2['0'] . '-' .$teste['1'] .'-'. $teste['0']. ' '. $teste2['1'].':00';

echo $final;
```

Works perfectly, but as you can see is nothing elegant. Someone with more experience might indicate a better solution?

Comment: How does `strtotime` not work? You have a different format in your solution.

Comment: @njk `d/m/Y H:m` is not a valid compound date time format.

Comment: @MarcusRecck I'm confused by the date OP says he's getting which is *12/20/2012*

Comment: He says he's getting `d/m/Y H:m` from the 3rd party, his example code reflects that.

Comment: "12/20/2012 14:34 -> d/m/Y H:m"   ?  Those don't go together.  It has to be either "20/12/2012" or "m/d/Y".  Which is it?

Comment: @MarkReed Not together, just added to facilitate the understanding of all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I came up with:

```
$date = '20/12/2012 14:34';
$date = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$date = strtotime($date);

$newdate = date('d-m-Y H:i:s', $date);
echo($newdate);
//returns 20-12-2012 14:34:00
```

I was rather confused on which formatting you were looking for, but you can switch around the date specifications inside the `date()` function. See [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) for more information on PHP `date()`.

Comment: The format I need is exactly what you went through, thanks.

This function generates no overhead on the server? My example is clearly bad for the server

Comment: I don't know about the performance of this script, but since it's a native function, I'd assume this is the most efficient way.